# The check_path "/login_check" for login method "form_login" is not matched by the firewall pattern "^/admin/(.*)"

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm creating a website with `Symfony 2.8` and `FOSUserBundle` for authentication.

I want the website to be public to anyone, and the back-office (with the prefix `/admin`) to be accessed after login authentication.

I just keep getting the error:

> The check_path "/login_check" for login method "form_login" is not
>   matched by the firewall pattern "^/admin/(.*)".

My `app/config/security.yml` looks like:

```
providers:

    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:

    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    admin:
        pattern:            ^/admin/(.*)
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            check_path:     /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /admin
        logout:
            path:           /logout
            target:         /login
        anonymous:    true

    main:
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/login_check, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I know there's something wrong in the `form_login`, but I just can't really grasp it...

**PS:** *Similar questions have been asked, but without great answers (or answers that work for me, for that matter).*

Answer (score 1):

I think your pattern need to be like that :

```
       admin:
            pattern: ^/admin/
```